# How do i make an add/remove css classes div in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a div that's change between CSS classes when clicking on it, clicking on it again will flip the div back. I'm trying to remove the class when clicking on the div the second time, but it seems that I don't do it the proper way.
How do I achieve this?

```js
    $('.snu').click(function () {
        $(this).find('.kort').addClass('snudd');
        });
  
     $('.snudd').click(function () {
        $(this).find('.kort').removeClass('snudd');
        });
```

```css
    body {
    background: #ccc;
}
.snu {
    -webkit-perspective: 800;
    -moz-perspective: 800;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px auto;
}
.snu .kort.snudd {
    -webkit-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
}
.snu .kort {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s;
}
.snu .kort .side {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 2;
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;
}
.snu .kort .forrand {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.snu .kort .bak {
    -webkit-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
    background: blue;
    background: white;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="snu">
    <div class="kort">
        <div class="side forrand">dette er forranddfsdfgsdfdsfgdsgfg</div>
        <div class="side bak">dett er  bakgdfgdfgdfg</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: define "flipping". it's not a real word you know

Comment: I've once made a component for this - https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/JKNGqO

Comment: Why not to use Animate.css?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following js

```
 $('.snu').click(function () {
    $(this).find('.kort').toggleClass('snudd');
    });
```

Comment: Than you very much.. can't believe it was so simple.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) in first event listener. You can't apply an event listener to a class that doesn't exist at the time the code is run

```js
$('.snu').click(function() {
  $(this).find('.kort').toggleClass('snudd');
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
}

.snu {
  -webkit-perspective: 800;
  -moz-perspective: 800;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.snu .kort.snudd {
  -webkit-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
}

.snu .kort {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s;
}

.snu .kort .side {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
}

.snu .kort .forrand {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.snu .kort .bak {
  -webkit-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
  background: blue;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="snu">
  <div class="kort">
    <div class="side forrand">dette er forranddfsdfgsdfdsfgdsgfg</div>
    <div class="side bak">dett er bakgdfgdfgdfg</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Than you very much.. can't believe it was so simple.

Answer (score 0):

with pure javascript

```
let snu = document.querySelector('.snu');
let kort = document.querySelector('.kort');

snu.onclick =  function() {
    kort.classList.toggle('snudd');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use of `toggleClass` :

```
$('.snu').click(function () {
    $(this).find('.kort').toggleClass('snudd');
});
```